# Run ControlValueAccessor validate after updating and validating child components

Tags: angular, typescript, controlvalueaccessor

I'm dealing with a tough problem in Angular. I want to create a custom form component that "bundles" several child input elements and is valid when all children are valid.

I thought I'd simply create a component implementing both the ControlValueAccessor and Validator interfaces. I'd inject the inputs with the ViewChildren decorator as NgModels so I could loop over them and collect any validation errors in the component's validate method. Here is a sample implementation for an address input component I made that does this for two inputs (street and street number) which both require a value :

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, forwardRef, OnInit, QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALIDATORS, NgModel, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ValidationErrors, Validator } from '@angular/forms';
import { Address } from './address';

@Component({
    selector: `address-input`,
    template: `
        <label for="street">Street</label>
        <input id="street" name="street" type="text" [(ngModel)]="Street" (blur)="onTouchedAField()" required /><br />
        <label for="number">Number</label>
        <input id="number" name="number" type="number" [(ngModel)]="Number" (blur)="onTouchedAField()" required />`,
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: AddressInputComponent,
            multi: true,
        },
        {
            provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
            useExisting: AddressInputComponent,
            multi: true,
        },
    ],
})
export class AddressInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
    @ViewChildren(NgModel) public validatedFields!: QueryList<NgModel>;

    private address: Address = new Address(null, null);

    private onFormCtrlChanged!: (_: any) => void;
    private onFormCtrlTouched!: (_: any) => void;

    public get Street(): string | null {
        if (this.address) {
            return this.address.Street;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public set Street(val: string) {
      this.address = new Address(val, this.address.Number);

        this.emitChanged();
    }

    public get Number(): number | null {
        if (this.address) {
            return this.address.Number;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public set Number(val: number | null) {
        this.address = new Address(this.address.Street, val);

        this.emitChanged();
    }

    public onTouchedAField(): void {
        this.emitTouched();
    }

    public writeValue(newAddress: Address): void {
        if (newAddress !== undefined) {
            this.address = newAddress;
        }
    }

    public registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
        this.onFormCtrlChanged = fn;
    }

    public registerOnTouched(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
        this.onFormCtrlTouched = fn;
    }

    public validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        let validationErrors: ValidationErrors | null = null;
        this.validatedFields.forEach((ngm: NgModel) => {
            console.log(`ValidationErrs for ${ngm.name} with value ${ngm.value}`, ngm.errors);
            if (ngm.errors !== null) {
                if (validationErrors === null)
                    validationErrors = {};
                validationErrors[ngm.name] = ngm.errors;
            }
        });

        console.log(`validationErrors `, validationErrors);
        return validationErrors;
    }

    private emitChanged(): void {
        this.onFormCtrlChanged(this.address);
    }

    private emitTouched(): void {
        this.onFormCtrlTouched(this.address);
    }
}
```

This mostly works fine when I embed the address component into a form like this:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #myForm="ngForm">
    <address-input name="address" [(ngModel)]="address" #addressInput="ngModel"></address-input>

    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

The only, but an annoying, issue is that when the address input component will be filled in correctly through a model binding the address input component will nevertheless remain in an invalid state.

I.e. when the app component containing the form that contains the custom form component defines the address field that it binds to the custom form component like so:

```
public address: Address = new Address('Baker Street', 123);
```

the custom form component should be valid but remains invalid.

When I then add a letter or digit to a field, for example, the custom form component immediately becomes valid.

After some investigation I noticed that this is because Angular calls the validate method of the Validator interface immediately after it calls the writeValue method of the ControlValueAccessor interface on the custom form component. That way, the values of the child inputs of the custom form component and their validation state are not updated yet when Angular calls the validate method on the custom form component.

To solve my issue, I am wondering if there is any way to force Angular to update the value and validation state of ngModels or to run validate again when child inputs/components have been updated. Or if there is any other way to make this work. More broadly, I am also wondering if there is a better way to implement a form component that is valid when all its children are, because I feel that fixing this issue is going to require some "hacks" or inefficient code.

[You can find a Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dngdam) containing a simple reproduction of the issue.

Thanks in advance for your time and help,
Joshua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code would be much simpler if you use ReactiveForms, in ReactiveForms you source of truth is the model and you always have access to the state of your individual control or group of controls without scanning component with @ViewChildren, here is very good example of how this is implemented from angular docs https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation

Comment: I'm quite sure that the QueryList is not the problem here. I use accessors to do the model binding in the example. When I put logging into the getters I see that the model values are only accessed for updating after validate has been called on my component ...

I do understand that reactive forms would probably be better here, but I can't use them since my team really dislikes them for some reason ...

Comment: You are right QueryList is not a problem, the problem is order of events in templated forms, which obviously do not work for you. You can try to hack it by checking if the validate call is first or not, but why to do it if Angular already have provided a better option. In fact TemplatedForms internally are build on top of reactive ones, so you use it probably without realising it :))

Comment: You were right, reactive forms were the way to go in this case. I implemented my component with the child inputs together in a FormGroup and things are working great now. If anyone wants to know the exact way I implemented it now, [check out this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqge2d)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using FormGroup controls to nest forms:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-1-creating-a-nested-group

Answer (score 0):

thanks for such a detailed explanation...I had a similar issue where a default value set on custom-component was not validating the wrapping component. After debugging realised that the onChangeCb() is still the one i initialized & not the one which registerOnChange assigns. So that changes were not propogating. Below is the change i tried & seems to be working. Please check

```
...
public registerOnChange(fn) {
            this._onChange = fn;
            /* value is model */
            this.value && setTimeout(()=>{this._onChange(this.value)},0);
        }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to one above, the below solution is better i feel as it does not invlolve any 'setTimeout'

```
public writeValue(val) {
// EXISING CODE
...

(val!==this.value) && this._onChange(this.value);

}
```